# python merge dataframes while choosing the keys conditionally

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

The simplified question for my problem is that I have a `lookup table` with many missing values under `id_A`:

```
first   last    id_A
A1      B1
A1      B1      C2
A3      B3      C4   
A4      B4
```

And I want to merge the lookup table with another table `table B` which also has missing values under `id_B`:

```
fName   lName   id_B    information_col
A1      B1      C1        104
A1      B1                29
A3      B3      C4        123
A4      B4                23
```

I want to merge these two dataframes on `left_on = 'id_A', right_on = 'id_B'` if possible. And for those with missing `id_A`'s or `id_B`'s, I want to merge the two dataframes on `left_on =['first','last'], right_on = ['fName','lName']`. The overall result would be like a left join, so that I only keep the data with keys shown in my lookup table.

I could achieve my goal with merging on `id_A` and on `first and last` separately, and then appending the two merged dataframes together, which is not efficient. I believe there are easier ways and I would like to hear your suggestions, thanks.

P.s. `first` / `fName` stand for first names, and `last` / `lName` mean last names.

The desired output would be:

```
first   last    id_A    information_col
A1      B1                  104
A1      B1      C2          29
A3      B3      C4          123
A4      B4                  23
```

Comment: Please post what the desired merge df looks like, I sorta understand but you need to post this so that there are no ambiguities

Comment: I'm assuming this is `pandas`? if so please update the tags

Comment: Thanks a lot @EdChum. And yes it's `pandas`. I've added the desired output for my example and added tag `pandas`.

Comment: Does data originate in a RDMS database? If so, consider using SQL as its engine and optimizer is much more efficient and can handle many types of joins (inner, outer, left/right, cross). Then, import result into Python.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. The data came from comma-delimited txt files downloaded from a web, but I think I would take your suggestion and use multiple joins to get my final results.